# How I do a repetitive operation that include one Integral

Tags: numerical-integration

I need calculate this integral

$\displaystyle F=\int_0^a xJ_0(\omega xy)e^{\frac{1}{2}\omega x}\, dx $

for some values of $\omega$. $a$ y $y$ are parameters that will be set while

$\omega$ will be get the values $\omega = 10, 11, 12$

I can calculate the value of this integral for each value of $\omega$ using this

```
In[1]:= f[y_?NumericQ, w_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[x*(BesselI[0, w*x*y])*Exp[0.5*w*x], {x, 0, a}]
```

given values of $y$, $w$ and $a$

```
In[2]:= f[0.1, 50, 10]
```

I get

```
Out[2]:= 8.659861518771908*10^2189
```

the problem is , I need to do this with a lot of values of $w$, the tutorial of Mathematica says I can do this with the command "Do", so i try this

```
In[3]:= Do[Print[f[0.1, w, 10], {w, 50, 60}]]
```

but not work at all :S, Mathematica just give this

```
f[0.1,w,10]{w,50,60}
```

Thanks in advance for any helpfull hint.

Comment: You misplaced the bracket: `Do[Print[f[0.1, w, 10]], {w, 50, 60}]`. But `values = Table[f[0.1, w, 10], {w, 50, 60}]` is better and you can access the list `values` for subsequent computations.

Answer (score 1):

```
f[y_?NumericQ, w_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ] :=
 NIntegrate[x*(BesselI[0, w*x*y])*Exp[w*x/2], {x, 0, a}]
```

Using pure [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) and [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html)

```
tab1 = f[1/10, #, 10] & /@ Range[50, 60]

(* {3.65614*10^128, 1.4318*10^131, 5.61038*10^133, 2.1996*10^136, 
 8.62833*10^138, 3.38636*10^141, 1.32971*10^144, 5.2238*10^146, 
 2.05314*10^149, 8.07316*10^151, 3.17582*10^154} *)
```

Using [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) as suggested by @corey979

```
tab2 = Table[f[1/10, w, 10], {w, 50, 60}]

(* {3.65614*10^128, 1.4318*10^131, 5.61038*10^133, 2.1996*10^136, 
 8.62833*10^138, 3.38636*10^141, 1.32971*10^144, 5.2238*10^146, 
 2.05314*10^149, 8.07316*10^151, 3.17582*10^154} *)
```

Using [`Do`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html) and remembering the values

```
tab3 = {}; Do[AppendTo[tab3, f[1/10, w, 10]], {w, 50, 60}]
```

Verifying equivalence,

```
tab1 == tab2 == tab3

(* True *)
```